# How does including a magic prefix to a JSON response work to prevent XSSI attacks?

Tags: api, json, xssi

While working on a project that used the REST API for Gerrit Code Review I noticed that they do something that I thought was strange [Source](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#output):

> To prevent against Cross Site Script Inclusion (XSSI) attacks, the JSON response body starts with a magic prefix line that must be stripped before feeding the rest of the response body to a JSON parser:

```
)]}'
[ ... valid JSON ... ]
```

How does prefixing the response body with seemingly random characters work to prevent XSSI?

Comment: By the way, Mozilla added support for parsing such responses in dev tools of Firefox 81.0.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1635835

Answer (score 19, accepted):

XSSI works by trying to evaluate a JSON response as Javascript and the sequence `)]}'` prevents this by reliably producing a syntax error.

There have been different proposed countermeasures against unwanted script inclusion, but putting an infinite loop (I have seen `for(;;)` used in Facebook APIs) or producing a syntax error (some Google APIs use `)]}'` as in your example) has shown to be sufficiently sound and is backward compatible. [This article](http://patorjk.com/blog/2013/02/05/crafty-tricks-for-avoiding-xssi/) has some additional examples.

If you're unsure about why XSSI is a threat in the first place and violates the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028511/what-is-cross-site-script-inclusion-xssi).

Comment: '...evaluate your JSON response as Javascript' Is that common?  It seems like a really unsafe practice.

Comment: @ecnepsnai It's a concept to overcome cross-origin restrictions and the core idea of JSONP. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: LOL -- "The browser's security mechanisms won't let me load this JSON data from a foreign source. I know! Embed the data inside javascript and eval() it!". That sounds like a terrible idea....