# Is JSON Hijacking different than JSONP injection?

Tags: json

I am quite confused while understanding these two vulnerabilities. 
How are JSONP-related vulnerabilities different from JSON Hijacking?

Comment: JSON hijacking is long dead, an issue in FF1.5 with Array constructors on non-jsonp non-cors responses. JSONP injection is where you're too generous with the allowed callback names, not sanitizing them enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is JSON Hijacking different than JSONP injection?

**Yes**, they are different attacks. While JSON hijacking is a threat from the past that's now eliminated in all major browsers, JSONP injection remains a security threat to web applications. Both attacks have in common that their goal is to read a JSON response from an untrusted origin.

## JSONP Injection

With JSONP (JSON with padding), an application deliberately provides a JSON response inside a function callback (or sometimes as an assignment), most often to overcome cross-origin boundaries.

E.g., the site `https://example.com/mySecrets?callback=saveSecrets` might return some "secrets" of the currently logged-in user, with the response looking like this:

```
saveSecrets({"userSecrets": [123, 456, 789]})
```

In this case, an attacker can define their own callback function (`saveSecrets`) and include the document as an external script to exfiltrate the secrets of the current user, along the lines of:

```
<script>
function saveSecrets(secrets) {
    alert(secrets);
}
</script>
<script src="https://example.com/mySecrets?callback=saveSecrets"></script>
```

(There are many other JSONP attack scenarios. You can find more of them with detailed explanations [here](https://securitycafe.ro/2017/01/18/practical-jsonp-injection/).)

## JSON Hijacking

JSON hijacking follows the same idea of exfiltrating a JSON response. But in this case, the application does not provide a convenient callback function. Instead, the attack relies on modifying native JS objects. Fortunately, this is not possible anymore in current browsers.

The text-book example is JSON inside an Array, e.g.:

```
[{"userSecrets": [123, 456, 789]}]
```

Years ago, when browsers allowed scripts to re-define native JS Objects, the way to extract the secrets was by defining your own `Array` constructor or hijacking the Object prototype with e.g. `Object.__defineSetter__` and then referencing the URL as an external script, similar to the JSONP example above.

(You can read more about JSON hijacking in [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/) or [my response here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/159615/95381).)